# How to propagate globally defined exception through execute immediate?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

Here is a minimal test case that for some reason fails with

> ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception

```
CREATE PACKAGE my_test
AS
  global_exception EXCEPTION;
END;
/

set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
  execute immediate 'BEGIN RAISE my_test.global_exception; END;';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_test.global_exception THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('global_exception');
END;
/
```

Here is a test case that works:

```
BEGIN
  RAISE my_test.global_exception;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_test.global_exception THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('global_exception');
END;
/
```

Is there a way to raise global exceptions through EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? 
Database version 12c or 11g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch it if you use [`dbms_sql`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm) instead of `execute immediate` (in 11gR2):

```
DECLARE
  l_cur pls_integer;
  l_rc pls_integer;
BEGIN
  l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse (l_cur, 'BEGIN RAISE my_test.global_exception; END;', dbms_sql.native);
  l_rc := dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_test.global_exception THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('global_exception');
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

global_exception
```

Not entirely sure why that works but yours doesn't though.

Ah, [investigating the different behaviour threw up a hint](http://plsql-challenge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/different-error-handling-behavior.html). You can catch it with `execute immediate` if you [associate an error number with the exception](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exceptioninit_pragma.htm) in your package:

```
CREATE PACKAGE my_test
AS
  global_exception EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA exception_init(global_exception, -20001);
END;
/

BEGIN
  execute immediate 'BEGIN RAISE my_test.global_exception; END;';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN my_test.global_exception THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('global_exception');
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

global_exception
```

You can now raise the exception statically in an anonymous block too, though that isn't very useful; without the pragma this also gets ORA-06510, as it is what you were doing within that `execute immediate`:

```
BEGIN
  RAISE my_test.global_exception;
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-20001: 
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

That ORA-20001 can now be thrown inside the `execute immediate` and the pragma allows it to be recognised through the context switch. Or something like that. The `dbms_sql` package handles it slightly differently, it seems.